# Applying Green's Theorem to evaluate line integral.

Tags: greens-theorem

I have to evaluate the line integral of the vector field
$$F(x,y)=\left(\frac{-2y}{x^2+y^{2}/4}+2x,\frac{2x}{x^{2}+y^{2}/4}+xy+1\right)$$
through $\gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the ounterclockwise unit circle.

I just want to know if I can use Green's Theorem here; I don't remember if I could apply it directly due to the fact that, if $x=y=0$ then the denominator above is equal to zero.

Comment: You can use Green's theorem on a non simply connected region instead. Notice that the line integral of the complicated component would be much easier on a certain ellipse rather than the unit circle. Use Green's theorem on the region bounded by the unit circle and that ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

Green's theorem requires that the function $F$ has partial derivatives which exist and are continuous over the entire interior of the interior of $\gamma$.  Since the partial derivatives of $F$ do not exist at $(0,0)$, this means that the conditions required for Green's theorem do not hold.

Comment: And is there something I could make to change this? I mean, to evaluate this line integral by its definition would be quite hard.